# Cappuccino File Tree

Tags: file, tree, cappuccino

Is there a way to build a file tree using Cappuccino with collapsible nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called a CPOutlineView.

You can supply a custom dataview which will allow you to display an icon right next to your text just like the finder does.

Comment: Thanks, it would be great if you could provide a code sample too.

Comment: Just like you create any other view var ov = [[CPOutlineView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMakeZero()]; // since you are adding to it a scrollview you dont need a real frame, it will be size correctly when you add it… then you will need to create a column. var col = [[CPTableColumn] initWithIdentifier:"my cool column"]; Then supply a custom dataview: [col setDataView:myDataView]; (see the docs on that since it requires you to implement CPCoding) add it to the ov [ov addTableColumn:col]; it's about as simple as that.